# Hadn't seen vs Haven't seen

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Please can you tell me which is correct - haven't or hadn't?

Situation:
I send picture to my friend and she replies:

> "I hadn't seen it yet"

Is it right use? Shouldn't be there "I haven't seen it yet"?

Thank you for help.

EDIT:
How about version without "yet"? Can I use both then?

Comment: The short answer to your question is that, "I hadn't seen it yet" is incorrect for two reasons (1) because of the 'yet' and (2) because it doesn't fit with the context.  On the other hand,  "I haven't seen it yet" is correct.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Please explain: " ...blah-blah-blah, or hadn't you noticed?" It sounds right. Anything else would sound wrong. But why?

Comment: @Ricky, well I commented because I didn't want to answer on this occasion. Maybe I will at some point--I don't exclude it.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Uh ... I believe my question is different from the OP's. But what do I know.

Comment: If you have a different question then please feel free to submit it. That's how the site works. We don't usually submit questions in comments.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I thought there was an easy, four-word explanation. I was wrong. I'm a miserable pathetic wretch. And promise next time to be quite reclaimed (Byron, I think).

Answer (score 5):

"I hadn't seen it" implies that you had not seen it (at that time) but you have now, while "I haven't seen it yet" implies that you still have not seen it (up to now).

"I hadn't seen it yet" is an incorrect mix of the two.

Comment: And without the "yet"? Which one is correct please?

Comment: Since your friend has now seen the picture, the correct sentence in this case would be "I hadn't seen it".

Comment: Note that "I hadn't seen it yet" is fine in some other contexts.